# $H_1$ and $H_2$ are pre-Hilbert Hausdorff space if and only if $H_1 \times H_2$ is pre-Hilbert Hausdorff space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, sesquilinear-forms

Let $H_1:=(H_1,B_1)$ and $H_2:=(H_2,B_2)$ are two pre-Hilbert spaces. Remembering that 'pre-Hilbert' means that $B_1$ and $B_2$ are non-negative sesquilinear forms in $H_1$ and $H_2$, respectively. Thus, $B_1$ and $B_2$ do not define a norm (define only seminorms). I want to prove that: $H_1$ and $H_2$ are Hausdorff space if and only if $H_1 \times H_2$ is Hausdorff space.

It's clear that $H:=(H_1\times H_2, B)$ is pre-Hibert space, where $B=B_1+B_2$.
Recalling that the topology in a 'pre-Hilbert' space is the topology generated by the seminorm (which is the sesquilinear form). I'm not able to taste the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**the answer seems long, but it is not, it is just detailed!**

I assume that $B((x,y),(x',y')):=B_1(x,x')+B_2(y,y')$. So in the product space $H_1\times H_2$ with the topology induced by the seminorm induced by $B$,the  basis consists of the sets
$$D_{(x,y)}(r):=\{(z,w)\in H_1\times H_2: \sqrt{B_1(x-z,x-z)+B_2(y-w,y-w)}<r\} $$
with $(x,y)\in H_1\times H_2$ and $r>0$.

Step 1: Observe that the topology of $(H_1\times H_2, B)$ is equivalent to the product topology of $(H_1, B_1)$ and $(H_2,B_2)$.

The product topology has as a basis the sets
$$D_x(r)\times D_y(r')=\{(z,w)\in H_1\times H_2: \sqrt{B_1(x-z,x-z)}<r\text{ and }\sqrt{B_2(y-w,y-w)}<r'\} $$
where $x\in H_1, y\in H_2$ and $r,r'>0$.

With some simple calculations we get that $D_{(x,y)}(r)\subset D_x(r)\times D_y(r)$ and that $D_x(r)\times D_y(r')\subset D_{(x,y)}(r+r')$, since for $s,t\geq0$ it is $\sqrt{s+t}\leq\sqrt{s}+\sqrt{t}$. This justifies that the topologies are equivalent.

Step 2: If $(X,\tau)$ and $(X,\tau')$ are two equivalent topologies on a space, then $(X,\tau)$ is Hausdorff if and only if $(X,\tau')$ is Hausdorff.

I leave this to you, it is easy.

Step 3: Let $(X,\tau_X)$ and $(Y,\tau_Y)$ be two topological spaces. It is true that $(X\times Y,\tau)$ (where $\tau$ is the product topology) is Hausdorff if and only if both $(X,\tau_X)$ and $(Y,\tau_Y)$ are Hausdorff.

This is again easy: for the converse, suppose that $(x,y), (x',y')$ are distinct points in $X\times Y$. Then either $x\neq x'$ or $y\neq y'$. WLOG assume that $x\neq x'$. Since $X$ is Hausdorff we can find $U,V\subset X$ neighborhoods of $x,x'$ respectively with $U\cap V=\emptyset$. The sets $U\times Y$ and $V\times Y$ are disjoint neighborhoods of $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ respectively.

Conversely, if $X\times Y$ is Hausdorff and $x\neq x'$ take $y\in Y$ and consider $(x,y), (x',y)$. These are distinct points in $X\times Y$, which is Hausdorff, so take disjoint neighborhoods of these points. Apply the projection onto $X$ (which is an open map) to obtain disjoint neighborhoods of $x$ and $x'$, which shows $X$ is Hausdorff (likewise for $Y$).

Comment: But it seems that in "for the converse" you don't use the hypothesis that $ Y $ is Hausdorff's space.

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno what if $x=x'$ but $y\neq y'$? Then I would have to use that $Y$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: But in this case, It seems to me that it is only necessary to assume that $ X $ **or** $ Y $ is Hausdorff's space. Because, $(x,y) \neq (x',y')$ implies $x\neq x'$ or $y\neq y'$.

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno You are wrong. Both spaces must be Hausdorff. When we have two distinct points $(x,y), (x',y')$ then: If $x\neq x'$, we will need that $X$ is Hausdorff. If we have that $y\neq y'$, we will need that $Y$ is Hausdorff. Since we need to show that for EVERY pair of distinct points in $X\times Y$, we will need both spaces to be Hausdorff.

Comment: True, I agree. Thanks for your great answer!

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno Glad I could help. Please consider accepting an answer so the question is filed as "answered" on math SE.